# linking static library with shared object

Tags: c, shared-libraries, static-libraries, undefined-reference

`OS : AIX53`

`Language : C`

I have a shared object

`[a.so]` which uses symbols in another static library `[b.a]`. The static library b.a is not supplied in the link line for creating a.so. Instead, it is supplied in the final executable binary which uses a.so.

When I run the executable, I am getting undefined symbol errors from a.so. These undefined symbols are those that are defined in b.a. Not sure what I am missing here.

Also, when I do an nm on both a.so and the executable, the symbols are not found. Should I be including b.a in the link line for a.so? I read it is not advisable to link static libraries compiled without fPIC into shared objects. Please advise.

Comment: for me, linking the `b.a` to the `a.so` is what works.

Comment: @Theolodis - Thanks for the response. But what I don't understand is when I link [b.a] with the final executable, shouldn't the symbols in [b.a] be automatically available to [a.so]? Why is it throwing undefined symbol error?